# wpdb insert formatting for date in array

Tags: wpdb

I have this simple wpdb->insert:

```
$this->wpdb->insert( 
'tablename',
 array(...., field1 => 'blahblah' , 'birthdate' => (isset($this->dob)) ? esc_attr(date('Y-m-d', strtotime($this->dob))) : null, ...) , 
array( ..... , '%s', date('Y-m-d'), .... ) 
);
```

to set format for date in the second array what I should put for wpdb?
Thanks in advance!
Cheers! :-)

Comment: are you asking how to insert a specific format you want to use? Or how to insert dates using `wpdb->insert` in a MySQL friendly format? Is the column type date/time/text/varchar?

Comment: Hi Tom... column type is a date which should follow unix format Y-m-d so I thought formatting with date('Y-m-d') would put in date format but it doesn't

Comment: if it doesn't insert the current date, what does it insert instead?

Comment: a date I select on <input type="date".... /> field that I pass to a property class

Comment: I meant, if it does not insert the value of the input tag of type date that you pass to a property class, what does it insert instead? blank? the current date/time? 1st Jan 1971?

Comment: Ah... it should insert just blank due that inline condition to check if it is settled or not but debugging a bit ago I figured it inserts 1970-01-01 out....

Comment: ok, so several questions, why are you using `esc_attr`? Where does `$this->dob` come from? How is it set? How are you validating that `$this->dob` contains a value? And if it isn't set you're passing `null` instead, is that intended?

Comment: esc_attr() is used usually to escape html attibutes especially from values, thats why.... I use $this->dob as class property because from another function I pass $this->dob = $_POST['dob'] where comes from input field and yes, if it isn't set I pass just null to $this->dob and if the record in db contains already a dob then $this->dob would be already set with that existing value....

Comment: escaping functions are intended to be used on output to the browser not for sanitising, `wpbd->insert` will sanitise it so it's safe to go into SQL for you. You'll need to edit your question to include all the code around `$this->dob`, this isn't just about how to use `$wpdb->insert`, `$this->dob` does not have the value you expect it to. Because it isn't set the code tells it to use `null`, which translates to `0` which means `0 seconds since January 1st 1971` and that's why it's saving 1971/jan/01